# Need to merge rows based on data within those rows

Tags: excel, vba

Specifically

Current condition:

```
Job Name     Sales Person    Job Value
Job ABC      John Doe        $200
Job ABC      Martha Doe      $200
Job ABC      Bill Anyguy     $200
```

Desired Result via Macro:

```
Job Name     Sales Person                          Job Value
Job ABC      John Doe, Martha Doe, Bill Anyguy     $200
```

Comment: are you grouping the names together because of the same job or because of the same price?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a solution based on the following hypotheses

- you are grouping people if their job is the same
- the jobs are already ordered, so for example in the first column you will NOT have cases like `job1`,`job2`,`job1` but only `job1`,`job1`,`job2`
- same jobs have the same price, otherwise when grouping the last one will be logged

A solution can be running the following Excel Macro `ExampleMacro` with the following setup. This code will filter the first worksheet [here `TotalList`] copying the content in a second worksheet [here `Grouped`]

NOTE: please use the same names I used or change the code of the following macro accordingly if you prefer to change the names. Otherwise it will not work

```
Sub ExampleMacro()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As String
Set ShMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TotalList")
Set ShSlave = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Grouped")

'cleanup for next macro executions
ShSlave.UsedRange.Clear

'copying the headers
ShSlave.Range("A1").Value = ShMaster.Range("A1").Value
ShSlave.Range("B1").Value = ShMaster.Range("B1").Value
ShSlave.Range("C1").Value = ShMaster.Range("C1").Value

'start processing
j = 2

'starting to check the master rows
For i = 2 To ShMaster.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    x = (ShMaster.Range("B" & i).Value)
    'checking if the job in the next rows is the same
    While StrComp((ShMaster.Range("A" & i).Value), (ShMaster.Range("A" & (i + 1)).Value), vbTextCompare) = 0
        x = x & ", " & (ShMaster.Range("B" & (i + 1)).Value)
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    
    'searching where to copy
    While ShSlave.Range("A" & j).Value <> ""
        j = j + 1
    Wend
    
    'copying
    ShSlave.Range("A" & j).Value = ShMaster.Range("A" & i).Value
    ShSlave.Range("B" & j).Value = x
    ShSlave.Range("C" & j).Value = ShMaster.Range("C" & i).Value

Next i
End Sub
```